# Server timestamp on Firestore document from javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to insert the created date on a document everytime is created (or updated).

I tried to use `firebase.database.ServerValue["TIMESTAMP"]` but It throws me `.sv:"timestamp"`

Any workaraund?

Comment: Please share the [minimal **complete** code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that it is unlikely we'll be able to help better than the [Firebase documentation on writing timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Answer (score 2):

I created a utility function for all database document creates and updates. The serverTimestamp() returns a sentinel which gets converted to the actual timestamp when the document is written/updates.

```
 private getNewMetadata(key?: string): shareTypes.documentMetadata {
    let metadata: shareTypes.documentMetadata = {
      createdAt: this.timestamp(),
      updatedAt: this.timestamp(),
      id: key || ""
    }

    return metadata;   }

 private timestamp(): any {
        return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      }
```